# How to define a condition when passing arguments to a function? ( coding more efficiently in python)

Tags: python, function, arguments, coding-efficiency

In this code, I have two functions **shoppingA** and **shoppingS** which share a number of lines. However, the arguments that I pass are slightly different. One takes two additional arguments. I am wondering how I can make the code more efficient by just having one shopping function and I could be able to pass the first two arguments if **model_index == 0** and pass four arguments if **model_index == 1**.

I should note that as these parameters will be used in other functions, I DO NOT want to define the GLOBAL.

```
model_index = 0

def shoppingA(agemean,agestd):
    global sum_prod, sum_sales
    age = agemean - agestd
    sum_prod += 1
    sum_sales += 20
    if sum_prod < 5 and age < 7:
        print("insufficient")
    
    
def shoppingS(agemean,agestd,randstd,randmean):
    global sum_prod, sum_sales
    age = agemean * randmean - agestd * randstd
    sum_prod += 1
    sum_sales += 1
    if sum_prod < 5 and age <7:
        print("insufficient")    
############################
def main(parameters):
    global sum_prod, sum_sales
    sum_prod = 0
    sum_sales = 0
    agemean = parameters[0]
    agestd = parameters[1]
    if model_index != 0: 
        randstd = parameters[2]
        randmean = parameters[3]
    if model_index == 0:
        shoppingA(agemean,agestd)
    else:
        shoppingS(agemean,agestd,randstd,randmean)       
###########################        
if model_index == 0:
    agemean = 5     
    agestd = 0.508           
    parameters = [agemean,agestd]
if model_index == 1:
    agemean = 8      
    agestd = 0.4       
    randstd = 9  
    randmean = 24.7    
    parameters = [agemean,agestd,randstd,randmean]   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = main(parameters)
```

In other words, I would like to do something like what you see below, where the arguments could be passed in a flexible way.

```
model_index = 0

def shopping():
    if model_index == 0:
        shopping(agemean,agestd)
    else:
        shopping(agemean,agestd,randstd,randmean)
    global sum_prod, sum_sales
    if model_index == 0:
        age = agemean - agestd
    else:
        age = agemean * randmean - agestd * randstd
    sum_prod += 1
    sum_sales += 20
    if sum_prod < 5 and age < 7:
        print("not_insufficient")

    
############################
def main(parameters):
    global sum_prod, sum_sales
    sum_prod = 0
    sum_sales = 0
    agemean = parameters[0]
    agestd = parameters[1]
    if model_index != 0: 
        randstd = parameters[2]
        randmean = parameters[3]
    shopping()  #####Only one shopping function
      
###########################        
if model_index == 0:
    agemean = 5     
    agestd = 0.508           
    parameters = [agemean,agestd]
if model_index == 1:
    agemean = 8      
    agestd = 0.4       
    randstd = 9  
    randmean = 24.7    
    parameters = [agemean,agestd,randstd,randmean]   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = main(parameters)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass 4 arguments in both cases. But if model_index is 0, pass 1 as last 2 arguments like below:

```
shoppingS(agemean,agestd,1,1);
```

because you are multiplying agemean by 3rd argument and agestd by 4th argument and then you are doing their substraction. So when 3rd and 4th arguments are 1, the multiplication will not change the values of 1st and 2nd arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a very quick follow-up question. If in the second shopping function, I need to get a social network, G, I can still do shoppingS(agemean,agestd,1,1,1) with the last 1 referring to the network. So, in cases where the network is not used, just 1 is passed, which does not do anything. Right?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with argument network. If you are going to do multiplication like 3rd and 4th argument, then passing value 1 will not affect your output.
Otherwise, you can pass empty/null value and check it in function. i.e. if the value of 3rd and 4th argument are empty or null (depends on what you passed), it will be your function with 2 arguments. Same can be done with argument no. 5.